# Diamond Shape isnt printing correctly

Tags: c++, shapes

Okay so I have to create this diamond shape, sort of, its supposed to be a diamond shape but with the top right half missing and the bottom left half missing. I have the two shapes down but they're not showing up in the diamond shape form, instead they are printing out one on top of the other.

I'm assuming somewhere. I have to print out the same amount of spaces to move the whole bottom shape to the right?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int row, col, siz;

   cout << "Enter the size of the diamond: " << endl;
   cin >> siz;

   cout << endl << endl;


   for(row = 1; row <= siz; row++){

      for(col = 1; col <= siz; col ++){
         if(col <= siz - row){
            cout << " ";
         }
         else{
                cout << "@";
             }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    for(row = 1; row <= siz; row++){

        for(col = row; col <= siz; col++){
            cout << "@";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stepping through the code with the debugger that almost certainly came with your development environment should make short work of this problem.

Comment: You didn't handle the spacing differently for upper and lower half separately.  See here http://www.sitesbay.com/cpp-program/cpp-print-diamond-of-star. And before posting a question here it is good to search on the net for the solution, you will get faster solution as well as community need not search for solution and provide you with the links. You will learn more by doing it yourself first. If still more problems, community is always ready to help you. While posting the question you should show some research of your own towards finding the solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

here my solution to your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int row, col, siz;

   cout << "Enter the size of the diamond: " << endl;
   cin >> siz;

   cout << endl << endl;

   // drawing top left side of diamon
   for(row = 1; row <= siz; row++){
      for(col = 1; col <= siz; col ++){
         if(col <= siz - row){
            cout << " ";
         }
         else{
                cout << "@";
             }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    // drawing bottom right side of diamon
    for(row = 1; row <= siz; row++){
        for(col = 1; col <= siz*2-row; col++){
            if(col<siz){
               cout << " "; 
            }
            else{
                cout << "@";
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation**: 
the first column of the second half has to draw first 'siz' time ' ' and then 'siz' time '@'. so it has to loop over siz*2; from then on you always have 'siz' time ' ' and then every time one less '@' so that is why the loop should look like `for(col = 1; col <= siz*2-row; col++)`

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my answer and if I understand your question, I think you are asking for the following shape.

```
          *
        * *
      * * *
    * * * *
  * * * * *
           * * * * *
           * * * *
           * * *
           * *
           *
```

It's diamond shape with missing top right and bottom left portion

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int row, col, size;

   cout << "Enter the size of the diamond: " << endl;
   cin >> size;

   for(row = 1; row <= size; row++){
    for (col = 1; col <= size; col++){
      if(col+row == (size / 2))
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
          cout <<"*";
      if(row >= size/2 && col >= size/2 )
        {
          if( col + row < size+size/2)
          cout <<"*";
        }
      else
       cout <<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I hope you find it helpful.